# Finding the nearest neighbour between coordinates in two separate lists

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, iterator, astropy

I have two galaxy catalogs and want to pair up each galaxy in catalog 1 with the closest galaxy from catalog 2. I have already written a script that does this for only one input catalog (not very efficiently but it works for what I need), which is posted below.

When I updated the code I've written for two catalogs, catalog 2 doesn't iterate further down the list than j = 3. It's getting stuck there for some reason.

Code for one catalog input:

```
def nnpairs(x):
"""
find nearest neighbour of each galaxy and pairs them up
"""
nearest_neighbours = []
shortest_distances = []
displacements = []
m_diffs = []
galaxies1 = []
galaxies2 = []
for i in range (len(x)):
    nearest_neighbour = []
    shortest_distance = []
    displacement = []
    m_diff = []
    galaxy1 = []
    galaxy2 = []
    for j in range(len(x)):
        if j == 0 and i!=j:
            shortest_distance = separation(x[i], x[j])
        if (separation(x[i], x[j])) < (shortest_distance) and i!=j: 
            shortest_distance = separation(x[i], x[j]) 
            nearest_neighbour = CATAID[i], CATAID[j]

            displacement = displacement_along_loa(x[i],x[j])
            dRA1, dRA2, dDEC1, dDEC2 = displacement
            galaxy1 = (CATAID[i], shortest_distance, dRA1, dDEC1)
            galaxy2 = (CATAID[j], shortest_distance, dRA2, dDEC2)
            m_diff = mass_diff(x[i],x[j])

    nearest_neighbours.append(nearest_neighbour)
    shortest_distances.append(shortest_distance)
    displacements.append(displacement)
    m_diffs.append(m_diff)
    galaxies1.append(galaxy1)
    galaxies2.append(galaxy2)

    data = list(zip(nearest_neighbours))
return data
```

Code for two catalogs:

```
    def nnpairs_2(catalog1, catalog2):
"""
find nearest neighbour of each galaxy and pairs them up
"""
nearest_neighbours = []
shortest_distances = []
displacements = []
m_diffs = []
for i in range (len(catalog1)):
    nearest_neighbour = []
    shortest_distance = []
    displacement = []
    m_diff = []
    j = 0
    while j < len(catalog2):
        if j == 0 and i!=0:
            shortest_distance = separation(catalog1[i], catalog2[j])
        if (separation(catalog1[i], catalog2[j])) < (shortest_distance) and i!=j: 
            shortest_distance = separation(catalog1[i], catalog2[j]) 
            nearest_neighbour = (i,j)
            displacement = displacement_along_loa(catalog1[i],catalog2[j])
            m_diff = mass_diff(catalog1[i],catalog2[j])
    j = j+1
    nearest_neighbours.append(nearest_neighbour)
    shortest_distances.append(shortest_distance)
    displacements.append(displacement)
    m_diffs.append(m_diff)

    data = list(zip(nearest_neighbours))
return data
```

The idea is that the code find the separation between every galaxy and creates the nearest neighbour pair for the smallest separation, but for the second code it only matches up all galaxies in catalog 1 with the third entry in catalog 2.

I understand there is quite a lot of information here but any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/matchsep.html#matching-catalogs; that does what you want with just one function.

Comment: As for your actual code: in the second code block, you have the while loop: `while j < len(catalog2):`. Yet you only increase `j` *outside* that loop (`j = j + 1`), so that the condition never changes (and the loop either never happens or is infinite).

Comment: I'll give that a try, many thanks. The only issue I can potentially envisage with using the astropy function is that I might lose some of the data I need to keep intact along the way. For example, after I've paired up each galaxy I then need to use their RA and DEC in 3 different filters to find the offset due to the gravitational attraction of the galaxies on each other in each pair. If the above method only gives the indexes of the galaxies matched up then this information might be lost. Do you have any experience with this? Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but I'm reasonably confident that you can always retrieve your original data using the indices. You may need to slightly change the data structures you use. If you find yourself running into problems with the `astropy.coordinates` functionality, that may warrant a new question. Because your comment has too little information (and uses an unconfirmed hypothesis) to be properly answered.